# Spree and Rails 3- How do I add a blog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

I have a simple rails 3 site consisting of blog,static pages and a gallery. I want to add a store to sell photos using spree. I have read through the guides and had a look at the source code but I'm still unsure of how spree integrates with an existing site.

Do I have to generate my blog model as an extension? (so I use the admin functionality of spree) and do the same for my other two models?

Are there any tutorials that cover this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1):

Right now there's a blog extension, maybe it helps you http://www.spreecommerce.com/extensions/100-blogging-spree-spree-0-30-rails-3-compat.
There are some problems with 0.40, though...

Answer (score 0):

The above link is broken. Here are two spree commerce extensions.

1. [spree essential blog](http://spreecommerce-extensions.com/extensions/spree_essential_blog) This one is a complete blogging solution for Spree Commerce with multiple-blogs, archives, categories, tags, disqus comments and related products. This extension relies on spree_essentials for it's editor, uploads admin and tab in the admin.
2. [spree simple cms](http://spreecommerce-extensions.com/extensions/spree_simple_cms) This extension add support of a simple CMS and Blog for Spree Commerce Shop,

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).